# erro no server rselenium scraping google scholar

Tags: r

Esta dando este erro. Qual seria a solução?

> checkForServer() Error in checkForServer() : could not find function
>   "xmlParse"

Answer (score 2):

Instale o pacote XML

```
install.packages("XML")
library("XML")
```